# get text for constraints in sql server

Tags: sql-server

In Sql Server we have a handy quick way of being able to fetch the text of stored procedures:

```
sp_helptext my_proc
```

Is there any other similarly quick way to return the definition of constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute the query to get the definition of constraints which are there in (sys.default_constraints, sys.check_constraints, sys.key_constraints, 
sys.foreign_keys...):

```
SELECT t.Name, c.Name, dc.Name, dc.definition
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints dc ON t.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
ORDER BY t.Name
```

Now to make it quick you can create a stored procedure which contains the above logic. And when executed the procedure will give you the desired constraint definition.

Comment: I was hoping there might be something shorter that I could remember with minimum effort

Comment: @jazza1000:- You can create a stored procedure and then use the above logic. As such I dont think there is no shorter way. however you can make a work around(*Updated in my answer as well*)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`sp_helpconstraint` + table_name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helpconstraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

It will return the full list of constraints on your table, constraint type, and what column the constraint is on.